# Bottom NavBar is not changing screen on tap of icon in Flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, bottom-navigation-bar

[From this image you can know where i'm tapping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yzvq.jpg)    My Bottom navBar is working fine in android but in IOS i have to press at the edge of the bottom for changing the screen.

This is my code

```
PersistentTabController? _controller;
  // int? userId = Get.find<GeneralController>().userData!.id;
  // List<Data>? branchList =  Get.find<BranchController>().allbranch;
  final generelController = Get.find<GeneralController>();
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  String? role;
  final home_Ar = "الرئيسية";
  final my_branch_Ar = "الفروع";
  final add_offer_Ar = "اضف اعلان";
  final pofile_Ar = "الملف الشخصي";
  final about_us_Ar = "من نحن";

  get menuScreenContext => menuScreenContext;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    role = generelController.userData!.role;
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    // notificationService.requestNotificationPermission();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: PersistentTabView.custom(context,
            controller: _controller,
            screens: _buildScreens(),
            confineInSafeArea: false,
            itemCount: 4,
            hideNavigationBar: false,
            onWillPop: (final context) async {
          await showDialog(
            context: menuScreenContext,
            useSafeArea: true,
            builder: (final context) => Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
          return false;
        },
            handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
            stateManagement: true,
            customWidget: Scaffold(
                bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
                    animationCurve: Curves.linear,
                    buttonBackgroundColor: AppColor.secondryColor,
                    color: AppColor.secondryColor,
                    backgroundColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
                    items:  [
            CurvedNavigationBarItem(child: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/images/booking.png"), color: AppColor.iconColor, size: 30,),),
            CurvedNavigationBarItem(child:ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/images/wallet.png"), color: AppColor.iconColor, size: 30,),),
            CurvedNavigationBarItem(child:Icon(Icons.chat, size: 30, color: AppColor.iconColor)),
            CurvedNavigationBarItem(child:Icon(Icons.settings, size: 30, color: AppColor.iconColor)),
                    ],
                    onTap: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = index;
                        if (index == 0) {
                          print("Home Screens");
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          print("Branch Screens");
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          print("Booking Slots");
                        }
                      });
                      _controller!.index = index;
                    }))),
      
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [BookingTabBar(), Wallet(), HomePage(), ProfileView()];
  }
```

I tried to implement different navbar those work fine in android but in IOS those were not working evene taping on bottom navbar icons
But curved navigation bar is working in the IOS but i have to tap below navbar icons.

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing the Scaffold widget from customeWidget.

Comment: If you already solved your problem then write an answer and mark it as solved.